# Gerar pdf em angular usando javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou tentando gerar um pdf na minha aplicação feita em angular e tenho o seguinte código no controller.js:

```
   function gerarPdf(){
        restService.relatorio.save({
          id: controller.contrato.id,
          folha: controller.receita.folha,
          descricao: controller.receita.desc},
          function (response){
            var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            window.open(fileURL, "EPrescription");
          },
          function(err){
            throw err;
          });
    }
```

Código do restService:

```
service.relatorioPart = $resource(REST_API.url + '/relatorios/participacao', {
    id: '@id',
    folha: '@folha',
    desc: '@descricao'
},
{
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
});
```

O código do método no controller do java:

```
@POST
@Secured
@Path("/participacao")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response imprimirRelatorioExtratoCoparticipacao(@Context HttpServletRequest request, HashMap<String, Object> filtros) throws PadraoException, Exception {
    try {

        Map dadosUsuario = restUtil.dadosUsuario(request);

        //Retorna um array de byte com os dados buscados no banco
        byte[] bytesRelatorio = nrelatorio.gerarBytesRelatorioExtratoCoparticipacao(filtros, dadosUsuario, "C:\\xxxx\\Desenvolvimento\\as-aplicacao\\");

        if (bytesRelatorio == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return Response.ok(bytesRelatorio).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

Realizando teste pelo Postman ele gera normalmente o pdf do relatório e já abre a janela de salvar o documento. Preciso que na minha aplicação ele também de essa opção de salvar ou abra uma nova janela exibindo o relatório.
[image: Com esse código acima ao dar no click no botão na tela chama a função geraPdf() ele dá o resultado]

Dei um console.log(response) para ver se ele estava trazendo o array de bytes e tive o resultado:

[image: Resultado do console.log(response) que veio do java]

Teste feito pelo postman:
[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][3]][3]

Acredito que por algum detalhe eu não estou conseguindo pegar esse array byte da api java e no angular converter para um documento pdf. Se alguém tiver conhecimento para me ajudar ficarei muito agradecida. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Não estou certo se isso pode funcionar para você, mas é a forma que faço para fazer download de CSV por ajax usando AngularJS. Você poderia criar um link no retorno da função e associar à URL o caminho do objeto criado...algo como:

```
$http({
    url: 'END_IP/relatorios/participacao',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        id: id,
        folha: folha,
        desc: desc
    }
}).success(function(data) {

    var a = document.createElement("a"); // cria o elemento
    document.body.appendChild(a); // adiciona no DOM
    a.style = "display: none"; // torna invisivel
    // \ufeff - para caracteres especiais
    var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", data], {
            type: 'application/pdf'
        }),
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "download.pdf";
    a.click(); // invoca o download do arquivo

    // para informar o navegador que não é mais necessário 
    //manter a referência para o arquivo
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

}).error(function(erro) {
    console.log(erro);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Já fiz algo parecido, a diferença é que o meu response no java retorna um ByteArrayInputStream. Tente o código mantendo seu código do java, caso não funcionar tente trocar byte[] por ByteArrayInputStream...  Resolvi da seguinte forma:

Adicionei o codigo abaixo dentro do resource

```
  cache: true,
  transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter, status) {
     var pdf = data;
     if (data && status < 400) {
        pdf = new Blob([data], {
          type: 'application/pdf'
        });
     }
     return {response: pdf};
   }
```

Então ficaria mais ou menos assim:

Seu controller:

```
restService.relatorio.save({
  id: controller.contrato.id,
  folha: controller.receita.folha,
  descricao: controller.receita.desc},
  function (response){
   var file = URL.createObjectURL(response.response);
   window.open(file);
  },
  function(respostaErro){
   // Aqui recupera alguma string caso o java retorne informando o erro
   var charCodeArray = Array.apply(null, new Uint8Array(
     respostaErro.data.response));
   var mensagem = '';
   for (var i = 0, len = charCodeArray.length; i < len; i++) {
     var code = charCodeArray[i];
     mensagem += String.fromCharCode(code);
   }
   alert(mensagem);
  });
```

Seu service:

```
service.relatorioPart = $resource(REST_API.url + '/relatorios/participacao', {
    id: '@id',
    folha: '@folha',
    desc: '@descricao'
},
{
  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  cache: true,
  transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter, status) {
     var pdf = data;
     if (data && status < 400) {
        pdf = new Blob([data], {
          type: 'application/pdf'
        });
     }
     return {response: pdf};
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso o que eu faço é o seguinte no angular:

```
window.location.href="http://localhost/suaapp/pdf?parametros"
```

Essa URL ira retornar um Response content type "application/pdf" e automaticamente o browser vai pedir pra fazer download.

Answer (score 0):

Dá para fazer da seguinte maneira:

criação do resource:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);

app.factory("PDFResource", function ($resource) {
    return $resource("REST_API.url + '/relatorios/participacao',
        {
             id: '@id',
             folha: '@folha',
             desc: '@descricao'
        },
        {
            'save' : {
                 method : 'POST',
                 responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                 transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter) {
                 return { data : data };
            }
        }
    });
)};
```

Seu Serviço:

```
@POST
@Secured
@Path("/participacao")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response imprimirRelatorioExtratoCoparticipacao(@Context HttpServletRequest request, HashMap<String, Object> filtros) throws              PadraoException, Exception {
    try {

        Map dadosUsuario = restUtil.dadosUsuario(request);
        //Retorna um array de byte com os dados buscados no banco
        byte[] bytesRelatorio =     nrelatorio.gerarBytesRelatorioExtratoCoparticipacao(filtros, dadosUsuario, "C:\\xxxx\\Desenvolvimento\\as-aplicacao\\");

        if (bytesRelatorio == null) {
            return Response.status(204).build();
        }

        return Response.ok(bytesRelatorio).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

E usaria da seguinte maneira:

```
PDFResource.save(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
}, function (err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

PDFResource deve ser injetado no seu controller