# Requisição Application/PDF gerando arquivo com informações erradas[AngularJS+NodeJS]

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express.js, pdf

Tenho uma aplicação AngularJs+Node(Express) totalmente Restless.
O back-end serve apenas para validar as requests e rotear para outras aplicações, detentoras das regras de negócio.

Em dado momento, meu front manda uma request para gerar um pdf, algo do tipo:

```
const callbackSucesso = function(resposta){                    
    if(resposta && resposta.data){
        let headers = resposta.headers();
        let blob = new Blob([resposta.data],{type: headers['content-type']} );
        saveAs(blob, "download.pdf");
    }else{
       //coisas que não importam aqui
    }
};
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/pdf',
    data: JSON.stringify(dto)
}).then(callbackSucesso,callbackErro);
```

Porém, quando eu abro o arquivo gerado, observo que há informações que estão distorcidas, por exemplo:
DESCRIÇÃO => DESCRIï¿½ï¿½O

Quando realizo pelo postman, o retorno da API é gerado normalmente como arquivo.

Já encontrei respostas que falam pra adicionar informações do tipo no objeto Blob - como essa: [Gerar pdf em angular usando javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172989/gerar-pdf-em-angular-usando-javascript) - porém o erro se manteve.

Quando tentei fazer no back-end, as saídas não foram muito diferentes.
Aí pensei em interceptar no node, gerar o arquivo, e redirecionar para o front.

```
   const fs = require('fs');
   ...
   request(options, function(error, resposta, corpo){
        if(error) {
           //não interessa para o contexto
        }else{
            fs.writeFileSync("10111.pdf", corpo,'binary');
           //aqui eu enviaria o link pro front baixar
        }
        next();
    });
```

Segui desse exemplo aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040014/how-to-save-pdf-in-proper-encoding-via-nodejs

Agradeço desde já a quem puder clarear minha estrada(!)

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução da forma que relato a seguir:

No back-end, que como comentei era apenas um roteador, optei por muda-lo para esse endpoint, de forma à receber a requisição que ele redireciona da seguinte maneira:

```
    //Gero minha requisição
        let options = gerarRequisicao("POST", endpointASerRedirecionadaARequest, req);
    //Crio um array para ir concatenando os valores recebidos via stream
        let pdf_buffer = []; 
    //Callback que será invocado ao completar a request. Observe que não utilizo o "body" que é fornecido, e sim o que  fui armazenando 
        const aoCompletar = (resposta,body) => { 
            // Aqui, concateno todos os valores que foram bufferizados.
            let data = Buffer.concat(pdf_buffer);
            resp.status(resposta.statusCode).json(data.toString('base64'));
        };

        request(options)
 /*Cada parte que recebo do meu stream, será adicionada no meu buffer, 
   que será utilizado no callback aoCompletar*/
            .on("data", d => pdf_buffer.push(d) )
            .on("complete", aoCompletar)
            .on("error", e => resp.status(500).json(geraMensagemDeErro(e)) );
        });
```

Me parece que o valor que é recebido como sendo o "body" da requisição via parâmetros no callback usado na hora da pergunta, parece que estava incompleto, ou algo assim.

Tomei por liberdade enviar do back para o front como base64 para garantir como irão as minhas requests.

No front, ao receber a resposta, converto o corpo pra um array, jogo num blob e realizo o download:

```
const callbackSucesso = function(resposta){                    
    if(respostaEstaValida(resposta)){
        let cabecalho = resposta.headers();
        let arquivo = converterBase64ParaBlob(resposta.data, cabecalho['content-type']);
        saveAs(arquivo, "download.pdf");
    }else{
        //não interessa para o contexto
    }
};
$http({        
    method: 'POST',
    url: `/api/pdf`,
    data: JSON.stringify(dto)
}).then(callbackSuceso,callbackErro);
```

Por fim, a conversão se dá da seguinte forma:

```
function converterBase64ParaBlob(base64, contentType){
    let respostaBruta = window.atob(base64);
    let tamanhoDaResposta = raw.length;
    let cache = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(tamanhoDaResposta ));
    for(let i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
        cache[i] = respostaBruta.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    let blob = new Blob([cache],{type: contentType} );
    return blob;
  }
```